# Run sequential jobs Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am using ChainMapper what happens is that they run in a pipeline fashion but what I want is that each mapper waits that the previous one has totally completed it's job.

Let's take the count words example where the firstmapper breaks the line to words, secondmapper counts uppercase word and thirdmapper counts the lower case words.

Now currently this runs in this fashion the secondmapper can start counting words even if the firstmapper has not finished reading the whole file.

What I want is to force the secondmapper to wait till the firstmapper has totally finished reading the input file then it can start.

My current configurations are the following:

```
JobConf conf = new JobConf(getConf(), ChainDriver.class);
        conf.setJobName("wordcount");

      ....

       //first mapper
        JobConf mapAConf = new JobConf(false);
        ChainMapper.addMapper(conf, TokenizerMapper.class, LongWritable.class,
                Text.class, Text.class, IntWritable.class, true, mapAConf);

        //secondmapper
        JobConf mapBConf = new JobConf(false);
        ChainMapper.addMapper(conf, UpperCaserMapper.class, Text.class,
                IntWritable.class, Text.class, IntWritable.class, true,
                mapBConf);
      .....

        JobConf reduceConf = new JobConf(false);
        ChainReducer.setReducer(conf, WordCountReducer.class, Text.class,
                IntWritable.class, Text.class, IntWritable.class, true,
                reduceConf);
   JobClient.runJob(conf);
        return 0;
    }
```

Is there a way to force the to run sequentially one after another ?

Comment: I am facing the same issue in my chained mapper, where both of them almost seem to be running simultaneously because the data set is very small. Did you manage to find  a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Chainmapper does run in a sequential manner.
Read this line:

```
The Mapper classes are invoked in a chained (or piped) fashion, the output of the first becomes the input of the second, and so on until the last Mapper, the output of the last Mapper will be written to the task's output.
```

You can find it here: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/ChainMapper.html

Comment: I want it to wait for the whole map function to wait. What it currently does is that it sends it to the next one in the chain even if the other mapper didn't finish. To be more clear what happens now is that each machine finishes and then the next mapper start. What I want is that all the machines finish before the next mapper can start.